# Insert arrays values into MySQL by gem 'mysql2'

Tags: mysql, ruby

I'm trying to insert arrays values into MySQL.

For example, I have three different arrays: `array_filename`, `array_filesize` and `array_filemd5`. Each one contains five values, so I need to insert each value one-by-one with something like:

```
query ( 'INSERT INTO info VALUES ( "array_filename_1", "array_filesize_1","array_filemd5_1")')
```

and using `.each`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need to see your attempt at solving this and why it didn't work or do what you wanted. Also, please don't use salutations like "good day!", valedictions or signatures. SO isn't a discussion board, it's a reference book. The links at the bottom of the "ask" page will help explain how to ask nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data in each array is indexed the same i.e. the rows you want are

```
array_filename[0]  array_filesize[0], array_filemd5[0] 
array_filename[1]  array_filesize[1], array_filemd5[1]
```

and the length of each array is the same, then just iterate and insert.

```
array_filename.length.times do |i|
  query = "INSERT INTO INFO VALUES (#{array_filename[i]}, #{array_filesize[i]}, #{array_filemd5[i]})"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query);
end
```

Comment: Woah, that's super crazy dangerous. Please, whenever possible use *prepared statements*. The [`exec_query`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-exec_query) function allows placeholders.

Comment: Done in this way
`$sql_name.length.times do |i|
     client.query ("INSERT INTO INFO VALUES ( 0, 'file', '#{$sql_name[i]}', #{$sql_size[i]}, '#{$sql_md5[i]}')")
  end`